# Why is my string showing a dollar sign in C

Tags: c

Ok, so I'm following a C tutorial and I went and typed

```
char name[4] = "foo";
name[1] = "z";
printf("%s",name);
```

output:

```
f$o
```

why is there a dollar sign? I'm expecting a "z" there

Comment: Why are you using quotes? `"`  You should use `'` for chars. `name[1] = 'z';`

Comment: Are you getting any warnings? If you aren't, you should throw your compiler away and get a new one.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a couple of steps back, and start over with some good book, tutorial or even a class.

Comment: Oh @Deanie your right! Mind if you post your answer so I can mark his question answered?

Comment: @machine_1 I'm using GNU GCC I don't think that's a problem cause if it is then we are [insert f-word here]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah i really do

Comment: @JazzHandy **GCC** will and **must** output a diagnostics message for this abomination. Your duty is to google for each and every message it utters to find out what you're doing wrong, or failing to find the answer then you can ask it here, provided that you add the warning/error message in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

> ```
> char name[4] = "foo";
> name[1] = "z";
> ```

*name* is an array of char but you assign a *char**, so you get a part of the address of it randomly producing a '$'

replace the second line by

```
name[1] = 'z';
```

it is surprising you do not get a warning when you compiled that line

I encourage you to compile with the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 0):

" " is used with strings. ' ' is used with characters.

```
char myChar = "h"; // WRONG
char myChar = 'h'; // RIGHT
```

name[1] represents a character, and "Z" is a string.  So

```
name[1] = "z";
```

should be:

```
name[1] = 'z';
```